# When I use `keras.datasets.cifar10` with model.fit it generates error

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow-datasets

I want to know the difference between `keras.dataset`and `tfds.load`. When I use the below code it works fine, Like:

`train_dataset, val_dataset = tfds.load( "tf_flowers", split=["train[:90%]", "train[90%:]"], as_supervised=True )`

`model.fit(train_dataset, validation_data=val_dataset, epochs=NUM_EPOCHS)`

But when I use the mode fit code with `keras.datasets` then it generates error that "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

`(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.cifar100.load_data()`

`model.fit(x_train, validation_data=y_train, epochs=NUM_EPOCHS)`

`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Link to my google colab code is [HERE](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1284uMdSdqrO4UfFN5hhAmu6EewvY5ala?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `tfds.load(.... , as_supervised=True )` returns datasets (tf.data) that already contains img and label together, but `keras.datasets.cifar100.load_data()` give you just arrays (img and label), so it should be like this:

```
model.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), epochs=NUM_EPOCHS)
```

Comment: Hi, Your answer seems to be helpful but now I am getting a new type of error (TypeError: forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'training')

Comment: This is a vision transformer model, may be it does not accept `model.fit()` in this way.

Comment: Then, you should add your model code to your post.  And I can try to recreate your error. I do not know what exactly is your goal, but here I find [Image classification with Vision Transformer](https://keras.io/examples/vision/image_classification_with_vision_transformer/) with same dataset and model.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train, ... ) works fine

Comment: I search about this error and in my case it is unmatched datasets because I used Tensorflow and pytorch datasets in same model. In future if Tensorflow and pytorch added the feature then we can use their datasets in same model.